# Python class method throws AttributeError

Tags: python, exception, flask, class-method, attributeerror

I'm having issues getting a class method to run in Flask.

In `models/User.py`:

```
from mongoengine import *

class User(Document):
  first_name = StringField()
  last_name = StringField()
  ...

  def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
    self.first_name = arg1
    self.last_name = arg2
    ...

  @classmethod
  def create(self, arg1, arg2, ...):
    #do some things like salting and hashing passwords...
    user = self(arg1, arg2, ...)
    user.save()
    return user
```

In the main application python file:

```
from models import User
...
def func():
  ...

  #Throws "AttributeError: type object 'User' has no attribute 'create'"
  user = User.create(arg1, arg2, ...)
```

Shouldn't I be able to call create on the User class without instantiating a User object? I'm using Python 2.7.2, and I also tried the non-decorator syntax of using `create = classmethod(create)`, but that didn't work. Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I found one issue: that the models folder did not contain an `__init__.py` file, so it wasn't a module, so `from models import User` was not actually importing the file I wanted it to.  It did not give me an error from before because I used to have a `models.py` module in the same directory as the application python script, but after deleting it I never deleted the corresponding `.pyc` file. Now, I'm getting the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'create'` instead of what I had before, but I'm certain it is importing the correct file now.

EDIT2: Solved. I then changed the import to `from models.User import User` and It's hitting the method now.

Comment: What is `User(arg1, arg2, ...): #constructor`? I don't think this is valid python syntax.

Comment: you must read docs before programming!

Comment: Try posting a minimal but complete sample of code that actually shows the problem you are getting. What you've done is paraphrase your code introducing new errors in the process and made it impossible for people to help you.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I was pretty tired when I wrote this and looking back at what I had written it made little sense.  Edited the post to more accurately reflect my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue was twofold:

1. The `User.py` file was in the `models/` folder, meaning that my import was actually looking for the `User` class in the `models.py` file, which no longer existed but still was being imported without error because the `models.pyc` file was still around
2. The import was incorrect for importing within a directory. it should have been `from models.User import User`, so long as the `models/` folder is a module, so all I needed to do then was `touch models/__init__.py`.

Comment: Cool, this makes sense and it saved me quite a bit of time as I had the same problem with stagnant pyc files.  And you're totally right to defend your question and to clarify that you already looked at the obvious solutions.

Comment: Yeah, "read the docs" isn't a very helpful answer—I wouldn't be asking on Stack Overflow if I hadn't! :)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> class foo(object):
...     def __init__(self):
...             pass
...     @classmethod
...     def classmethod(cls):
...             return 0
...
>>> a = foo()
>>> a.classmethod()
0
>>>
```

Comment: Sorry, my question was pretty badly written.  This already was done, but class methods still don't work.

Comment: @OmarDiab if you using classmethod decorator your first argument should be `cls` not `self` http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#classmethod

Comment: I tried using cls and I tried using self. Both give me the same error. I read the documentation on this, and I don't see where my code is going wrong.  Which is why I'm asking on Stack Overflow. I'm sorry if I'm offending you somehow, but the reason I'm asking this here is because I don't see how I'm straying from the documentation, and your sass isn't helping me solve anything. If it means anything I wrote this in terms of generic Foo and Bar classes with no dependencies on other modules and it did work. So I guess I'll play with this more but if anyone has insights I'd love to hear.

Comment: @ZagorulkinDmitry Using `cls` versus `self` is important for sticking with convention, but doesn't explain the error. Also, your example has non-conventional casing and indentation, and doesn't illustrate the use of `cls`.